# How to create a schedule with two different types of week? Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, schedule

I want to create a bot, that will show me the schedule for two different types of week (numerator and denominator), because we had different lessons on different weeks. Here is a small part of my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def what_week_now():
    my_date = datetime(2020, 3, 16)  # the year, month, day of the reference week
    days = (datetime.now() - my_date).days  # difference in days
    days -= days % 7  # align on monday


    if days % 14 == 0:
        return 1  # numerator week
    else:
        return 0  # denominator week

# determining the day of the week for today, as an example

if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    print("Monday lesson list")
if date.today().weekday() == 1:
    print("Tuesday lesson list")
```

The main question is how to use this function to create two different types of lesson list for one week day (for example monday lesson list 1 for numerator week and monday lesson list 2 for denominator week)?

Comment: you can schedule cron jobs and provide the path of python program to run.
Or refer: https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the function inside another nested-if, like this:

```
if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    if what_week_now() == 0:
        print("Monday lesson list denominator")
    else:
        print("Monday lesson list enumerator")
if date.today().weekday() == 1:
    if what_week_now() == 0:
        print("Tuesday lesson list denominator")
    else:
        print("Tuesday lesson list enumerator")
```

Another alternative is doing it like this:

```
if what_week_now() == 0:
    if date.today().weekday() == 0:
        print("Monday lesson list denominator")
    if date.today().weekday() == 1:
        print("Tuesday lesson list denominator")
else:
    if date.today().weekday() == 0:
        print("Monday lesson list enumerator")
    if date.today().weekday() == 1:
        print("Tuesday lesson list enumerator")
```